# how to make this codes Descending order

Tags: java

How to make this codes descending order..?

```
for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
  for (int y = x + 1; y < a.length; y++) {
     String Name1 = a[y].getBrand(); 
     String Name2 = a[x].getBrand();
     if (Name1.compareTo(Name2) <= 0) {
         Get temp = a[x];
         a[x] = a[y];
         a[y] = temp;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: The web is full of sorting algorithms. Find one that fits to your needs.

Answer (score 5):

Just change at the comparitation like this :

```
if (Name1.compareTo(Name2) >= 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
private static final Comparator<Get> DESC = new Comparator<Get>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final Get a, final Get b)
    {
        return b.getBrand().compareTo(a.getBrand());
    }
}


// In code...
Arrays.sort(theArray, DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use **Arrays.sort()**
this will make your issue run away.